# c++ template type matching with references

Tags: c++, templates

When I run the following code, an error occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class M {
 public:
  M(): a(0), b(0) {}
  M(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
 private:
  int a;
  int b;
};

template <typename T>
class Test {
 public:
  Test(const T& my) { }
  T my_;
};

template <typename T>
using ReferTest = Test<T&>;

int main()
{
   ReferTest<M> t2(M(3,4));
}
```

Error is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25:20: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘M&’ to an rvalue of type ‘M’
   25 |    ReferTest<M> t2(M(3,4));
      |                    ^~~~~~
main.cpp:16:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Test<T>::Test(const T&) [with T = M&]’
   16 |   Test(const T& my) { }
      |        ~~~~~~~~~^~
```

"cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘M&’ to an rvalue of type ‘M’" confuses me, I understand M(3,4) is an rvalue, but the type in the constructor of Test is "const T&", instead of "non-const".

Comment: Thanks, I will learn it and modify my question.@Yunnosch

Comment: You try to substitute `const T&` with `T=M&`, you get "reference to (const T)" where T is a reference to M. But references themselves are never const, so this const gets thrown away.

Comment: Another case of "leading const is misleading".  I kid you not, if you switch to `T const&` instead, and do the substitutiom n.m. suggests, the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: Look carefully here: `template <typename T> using ReferTest = Test<T&>;` and see whether you don't see a missing `const` somewhere. When you fix that, it still won't compile though (you need to initialize `Test::my_` for it to compile).

Comment: A slightly smaller example of the same situation: `Test<int&> t2(1);`.

Comment: It is slightly unintuitive that, despite being immutable, references themselves can't be `const`. On its own, `T& const` is invalid for all types `T`, and if you happen to "add" the `const` through a template instantiation it is silently removed. "Reference to reference" also gets "collapsed" in templates, so the instantiation `const (M&) &`  (`i.e. M& const &`) becomes `M&`.

Comment: On a side note, it is very rare to use reference types as template arguments. I don't think have ever seen it "in the wild".

Comment: @molbdnilo the reason being it is too easy to end up with dangling references

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a forwarding reference in your template not a const& like this, which then copies the temporary. Using references to temporary object like you is tricky at best.

```
#include <iostream>

// don't use using namespace std;

class M 
{
 public:
  M(): a(0), b(0) {}
  M(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}

  ~M(){ std::cout << "deleting M\n"; }
  int get_a() const noexcept { return a; };

 private:
  int a;
  int b;
};

template <typename T>
class Test {
 public:
  Test(T&& my) : // <== forwarding here
  my_{std::forward<T>(my) } 
  {
  }

  T my_;
};

template <typename T>
using ReferTest = Test<T>; // <== no reference here!

int main()
{
    ReferTest<M> t2(M{3,4}); // <== M's temporary will be deleted after this line! So it is not safe to have a reference to it after this line.
    std::cout << t2.my_.get_a();
}
```